# How to customize mdToast (to center)

Tags: angular-material

Angular Material `mdToast` service documentation shows the position can be any combination of `'bottom', 'left', 'top', 'right', 'fit'`.
 How do I customize the toast to show at `'top center'` position?
 what is  this `'fit'` option for? changing the demo code to below did not help

```
 $mdToast.simple()
        .content('Simple Toast!')
        .position('fit') 
        .hideDelay(3000)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why there is no 'center' position for mdToast?

Comment: it may helps Dude :- https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1773  check it out

Comment: ^ Please +1 the GitHub issue above if you haven't already. This should be easier...

Comment: its coming - https://github.com/angular/material/pull/8269/commits

Answer (score 4):

if you want to center the toast just add

```
md-toast.md-top {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

to your CSS and you are all set. -150 is half the width of my toast

Answer (score 3):

With the latest release (1.0.0 stable), this is how it's done:

Add the below to your CSS

```
md-toast.md-center {
left: 50%;
transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
}
```

and this to your angular

```
$mdToast.simple()
  .textContent(message)
  .position('top center')  // or 'bottom center
  .show();
```

Comment: it worked for me with the toastClass method and this styles, thank you!